# Did Tony base J.A.R.V.I.S. off of the real Avengers butler?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

J.A.R.V.I.S., the advanced A.I. which formed the basis for Vision's personality, has been prominent in the MCU from the start. In the first  **Iron Man** film, he's shown as a program that basically serves as Tony's right hand, both in most technical capacities, and in mundane everyday tasks. He was then transferred to the synthoid body Ultron created, gaining further sentience and the capacity for emotions and becoming the Vision. This is *semi-close* to comic book Vision's actual origins, in that his A.I.'s "neural patterns" were based on that of the then-comatose Avenger, Wonder Man, who has yet to appear in the films.

However, in the comics, Jarvis has taken several incarnations.

Prior to the late 2000s, Jarvis was an actual *person*  who served as the Butler at Avengers Mansion. Supposedly, he was hired by Tony to be the "man in the chair" for the Avengers, serving as attache, messenger, cleaner, cook, keeper of their information center, limited bodyguard and tactical hub on some missions. I *know* he was a real person, because at one point he was dating Aunt May Parker.
Later stories, however, made it seem like the Jarvis "person" was either a hologram, or an android.

I don't know if it's a case of occurring in different universes [J.A.R.V.I.S. seems to have been an A.I. in the *Ultimates* 1610 world] or if the movies influencing the comics, but its been generally accepted that Jarvis is a computer program now; I haven't seen a "live person" version in some time.

So I was wondering:

Did something happen to the "person" Jarvis, and he's now been "uplinked" to a computer, or is the A.I. J.A.R.V.I.S. just *based* on the person as a kind of tribute?

And if so, is Jarvis [the butler] still alive and well, and if so, where is he now?

Comment: Edwin Jarvis was a main character in the MCU television series [_Agent Carter_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Carter_(TV_series)) who also had a cameo in _Avengers:  Endgame_.

Comment: @eshier An interesting fact, but not conclusive. Did Tony _know_ this character and then use him as the basis for the A.I.? Was he a servant prior to the Avengers forming [never watched  _Agent Carter_ so I only know it followed the adventures of Peggie post _Captain America:TFA._  The fact that he made a cameo in _Endgame_ means that yes, he existed, but did he _serve_ the avengers in the same capacity?

Comment: He was Howard Stark's butler/assistant (that's when the cameo appears when Howard is leaving the base).  Tony grew up with him, I believe.  I'd assume it was named in his honor as the voice is a different actor, but not sure if it is ever stated.

Comment: @eshier That would make sense; Tony basiing a right-hand A.I. off a man he had seen be his dad's right hand would be a fitting tribute. So there is a basis in the movie. any idea what happened to the "real-life" Jarvis in the comics, though?

Comment: Per wiki: it's simply named after Ed Jarvis.  *Just A Rather Very Intelligent System (J.A.R.V.I.S.) was originally Tony Stark's natural-language user interface computer system, named after Edwin Jarvis, the butler who worked for Howard Stark.*

Comment: Regarding his status, Edwin Jarvis is currently *deceased*

Comment: @Shreedhar That's sad. Any information on when or how Jarvis passed away, then?

Comment: @RussRainford I don't think it's ever said but most certainly old age considering he's from the WW2 era (in the MCU again).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot True enough. If he was dating _May Parker_ then dude would have some years on him. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: You have a lot of misunderstanding of the source material in you answer. In the Ultimates universe (1610), Edwin Jarvis is a human, and Tony's butler (not an AI). Jarvis in 616 is still very much alive and human and has an important role in https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_No_Surrender and as a supporting character in https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Unstoppable_Wasp_Vol_1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

J.A.R.V.I.S. in the MCU is an artificial intelligence that stands for Just A Rather Very Intelligent System. However, this is a handy acronym as J.A.R.V.I.S. is named after Edwin Jarvis a butler for the Stark family and father figure for Tony. We don't see much of Jarvis in the MCU films, although he does appear in *Agent Carter*, and only get a glimpse of him in *Avengers: Endgame* back in Camp Leigh when Tony and Cap go there.

However, in *Iron Man 2: Public Identity* Issue 2, a canon comic to the MCU, it is somewhat revealed that Tony does appear to have named J.A.R.V.I.S. after Edwin Jarvis.

[image: Comic panels where Tony states "Jarvis" has always been there] [image: Comic panels where Tony recalls "Jarvis" being happy to see him]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Seems like that does tie it together. However, if this is the 616 universe, in which Edwin Jarvis was an actual person who used to date May Parker, what then happened to the _original_ Jarvis? He was serving at Avengers Mansion up until the early 2000s, last I recall....

Comment: @RussRainford My answer is referring to the MCU (Earth-199999) only not the main comics continuity (Earth-616) as I thought you was asking about the MCU.